# vbscript split string with colon delimiter

Tags: vbscript

I have a project which receives a delimited string through SMS. I am tasked to split the string by colon (`:`) using the `Split` function. My SMS server receives the messages and my script processes it.

Sample code:

```
dim a 
a = split(string,delimiter)
dim value
value = a(1)
```

Sample input (SMS message): `abc:def ghi:jkl`

Now when I split it, I was expecting `value` to return only `def`, but I get `defghi` instead. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your output is correct, `split()` creates an array of substrings which are determined by the delimiter provided.

The substring `"def ghi"` is due to whitespace being used to separate the characters instead of a colon.

If you don't want the whitespace you can use split again with no given delimiter, `" "` is the default used when one isn't provided.

e.g. `split(value1)`

You could also try checking the received string for spaces and replacing any found with colons and then proceed as normal.

Comment: actually i tried this split(string) then dim value value = split(string(1), ":") to get the desired value but is it ok?

Comment: You can do it that way too, splitting by space and then the colon.