# In VBScript how do you take a string using mid and split the string at say a ";"

Tags: vbscript

So I am newer to VBScript and struggling taking a string and remove/splitting it. I currently have:

```
id= mid(storeline,id,instr(id,storeline, ";",1))
```

I essentially want to rid of any code after the ";". 
For example: `ID:12049302; Height = 20;` I currently have it returning everything. Any help is awesome thanks.

Comment: Suggest you lookup how to use [`Mid()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3(v=vs.84).aspx) and [`InStr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c(v=vs.84).aspx). You might find [`Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5(v=vs.84).aspx) useful for this scenario, that and the definition of [concatenation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation).

Comment: Concatenate means "to combine", but it sounds like you want to "split" the string at the ";"?

Comment: Sorry yes I ment split/remove

Comment: You need to use `left` rather than `mid` (which stands for middle) if you want the beginning of a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vbscript split string with colon delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649495/vbscript-split-string-with-colon-delimiter)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Split()` to break your string down based on the `;` delimiter value like so;

```vb
Dim storeline: storeline = "ID:12049302; Height = 20;"
Dim data: data = Split(storeline, ";")
Dim entry

If IsArray(data) Then
  'Return just the first entry
  WScript.Echo "Result is " & Trim(data(0) & "")

  'Use a loop to iterate through the Array
  For Each entry In data
    entry = Trim(entry & "")
    WScript.Echo entry
  Next
End If
```

Output:

```
Result is ID:12049302   
ID:12049302
Height = 20
```

Comment: Can we say that storeline contains a string large enough to hold many attributes and ect. Essentially picking out the id and then breaking the string down at the semi-colon

Comment: @AustinEfnor I've just showed two methods of accessing the array items, if you want to identify one by say `ID` you could do the loop like above and  check something like `If Trim(Split(entry, ":")(0)) = "ID" Then` for example. You have to understand I've answered based on the information provided in the question, it is far from a solution more a guide.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `storeline = "ID:12049302; Height = 20;"` then

```
myArray = Split(storeline, ";")
id = myArray(0) ' will contain "ID:12049302"
```